# boost::asio::ssl access violation on multi-threaded application

Tags: c++, ssl, boost-asio

I've created a program that makes use of boost's ssl implementation to send and receive small packets to a remote server using `async_read_some()` and `async_write_some()`. The read and write are wrapped in a strand to prevent concurrent reading and writing. Additionally the wrapper functions I've created for each contain a mutex to further prevent concurrent access (possibly overkill, but can't hurt). The writes are stored on a write queue where they are sent when the thread is notified that data is available.

The issue I'm experiencing occurs when a large number of writes are executed sequentially, resulting in varying errors such as Second Chance Assertion Failed and Access Violation. I also get a read error of "decryption failed or bad record mac".

From the research I've done so far, I've found that SSL sockets can become corrupted if reads and writes are performed concurrently - at least according to the discussions [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/5548) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467630/clarifying-openssl-0-9-8l-concurrency-support-can-ssl-instances-be-used-by-mul) where the OP's symptoms are very similar to mine. He also states that the strand he was using was not functioning, but I don't understand his solution. This would make sense with the issues I'm having due to the methods I'm attempting to use to prevent concurrent reads and writes.

A workaround I've been using is to throttle the sequential writes so that there's a gap of at least 20ms between each. Any less than this and I start getting errors. This workaround isn't great though, because at some point there may still be a concurrent read/write resulting in errors.

Here's a summary of my read/write code:

```
void client::write(std::string message, char packetType) {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::shared_mutex> lock(writeInProgressMutex);

    std::string preparedMessage = prepareWrite(message, packetType);
    char data_sent[2048];

    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < preparedMessage.size(); ++i) {
        data_sent[i] = preparedMessage[i];
        if (i + 1 == preparedMessage.size()) {
            data_sent[i+1] = NULL;
        }
    }

    socket_->async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_sent), strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
}

void client::read() {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::shared_mutex> lock(readInProgressMutex);
    socket_->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_), strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
}
```

I've experimented with different types of mutexes, so I don't think that is the issue. If anyone knows a way to ensure my strand is doing its job or you can see some obvious errors in my code/design please let me know!

Comment: Do you use more than one thread invoking `io_service::run()`? If so, does the problem go away when you use a single thread?

Comment: Please update the code in your question with how you use an explicit `strand` to ensure at most one async ssl operation is outstanding.

Comment: @SamMiller I think the strand is where the problem lies. My original implementation was allowing multiple writes while the read operation was still in progress. I'm reworking some of the code now to see if I can make some progress with it - I'll report back what I've changed if I'm still having issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, verify that all calls to `client::write()` and `client::read()` are running within `strand_`.  Without additional code, synchronization constructs, such as a mutex, will be ineffective for preventing concurrent operations from being invoked.

---

The Boost.Asio documentation for [`ssl::stream` thread safety](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html#boost_asio.reference.ssl__stream.thread_safety) accentuates the `strand` requirement:

> *Distinct objects:* Safe.
>
> *Shared objects:* Unsafe. The application must also ensure that all asynchronous operations are performed within the same implicit or explicit strand.

If the `ssl::stream` operations are only being invoked within a single thread, then it is safe as they are running within an implicit strand.  On the other hand, if multiple threads are invoking operations on an `ssl::stream`, then they must be explicitly synchronized with a strand.  Other synchronization constructs, such as a mutex, will be ineffective due to intermediate handlers without introducing custom [`asio_handler_invoke`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html) functions.

Here is a flow diagram showing the necessary strand usage for an asynchronous write chain:

```
void client::start_write_chain()
{
  strand_.post(boost::bind(&client::write, ...)) ---.
}    .----------------------------------------------'
     |  .-------------------------------------------.
     V  V                                           |
void client::write(...)                             |
{                                                   |
  ...                                               |
  socket_->async_write_some(buffer, strand_.wrap(   |
    boost::bind(&client::handle_write, ...)));  --. | 
}    .--------------------------------------------' |
     V                                              |
void client::handle_write(                          |
  boost::system::error_code& error,                 |
  std::size_t bytes_transferred)                    |
{                                                   |
  // If there is still data remaining.              |
  if (bytes_transferred < all_data)                 |
    write(...);  -----------------------------------'
}
```

This requirement is the result of an implementation detail that `ssl::stream` asynchronous operations are implemented in terms of composed operations.  The initial operation may occur within the context of the caller, and thus `client::write()` needs to be invoked from within `strand_`.  These composed operations may result in many intermediate calls to `socket_`.  With these intermediate calls having no knowledge of `writeInProgressMutex`, the mutex becomes ineffective for protecting `socket_`.  Consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1053968) answer for more details on composed operations and `strands`.

Additionally, within `client::write()`, the lifetime of the buffer `data_sent` fails to meet requirement for [`ssl::stream::async_write_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/async_write_some.html), which states:

> Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of the underlying buffers is retained by the caller, which must guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called.

In this case, `data_sent`'s lifetime ends when `client::write()` returns, which may occur before the completion handler has been invoked.

Comment: Yep, it was a problem with `read()` not being invoked from within the `strand_` resulting in concurrent reads and writes. I had incorrectly assumed that since the `async_connect()` and `async_handshake()` were invoked through the `strand_` that the `async_read()` would be too. Adding `strand_.post(&client::read())` seems to have fixed the problem! Thank you. Can you explain a bit more about how I can guarantee the lifetime of data_sent?

Comment: @user2753546:  Consider either making `data_sent` a member variable of `client`, or allocate and manage the buffer in the free store.